# How can I redirect users to different pages based on get url in PHP?

Tags: php, url, get

I'm building a blog .
I want to redirect users who tried to access a post page , without get parameter to thr previous page (if possible without `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`)

Exemple : `www.myblog.com/post.php`

And allow access to this page only via this url

```
www.myblog.com/post.php?id=number
```

Comment: *"without get parameter"* and without `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. No idea. Can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Yes , if user delete `?id=number` he will get to root file and there nothing on it ...

Comment: you have answers below, that some pretty much do what I had in mind. see if any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a session variable.

First, in the script that accesses to post.php you need start the session and you need know the id, for example:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['post_id'] = $id; //$id is the post id
```

Next, in post.php start the session and you can use the id to redirect, do a sql query.......

Answer (score 2):

You can use this PHP Codes if id is not set or empty, just choose here
I would Recommend to use empty() function:

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'])) {
header("location: url");
}
```

or

```
if($_GET['id'] == NULL) {
header("location: url");
}
```

or

```
if(empty($_GET['id'])) {
header("location: url");
}
```

Comment: OP: *"without get parameter"*